# Python pickling error when using sessions

Tags: python, django, session-variables, pickle

In my django app I was creating an extended user profile using session vars. But when registration form was saved and user was about to create, I got following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 279, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)

  File "\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 651, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)

  File "\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 245, in __call__
    response = middleware_method(request, response)

  File "\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\middleware.py", line 36, in process_response
    request.session.save()

  File "\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\db.py", line 53, in save
    session_data = self.encode(self._get_session(no_load=must_create)),

  File "\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\sessions\backends\base.py", line 88, in encode
    pickled = pickle.dumps(session_dict, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'cStringIO.StringO'>: attribute lookup cStringIO.StringO failed
```

I've googled for an answer, but found nothing interesting. Any workarounds for this ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post your code as well!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you have a cStringIO object in your session (perhaps an uploaded file?), these cannot be pickled. Either write custom pickling code or make sure all your session data can be serialized.

Answer (score 1):

Something weird going on here, because the error refers to `cStringIO.StringO` whereas the class is actually `cStringIO.StringIO`, with an extra I. Have you misspelled the name somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

In support of Ivo's answer, here's a reference I found which may explain this: [http://bugs.python.org/issue5345](http://bugs.python.org/issue5345/)

> This is not a typo. cStringIO.StringIO
>   is a factory function that returns
>   either a cStringO object (for writing)
>   or cStringI (for reading). If this
>   behavior causes a problem to you, then
>   consider using StringIO.StringIO.
>
> Alternatively, you could upgrade to
>   Python 2.7 or 3.0 and use
>   io.StringIO() which doesn't have this
>   limitation.