# Multiprocessing: AttributeError: StdIn instance has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I get this error with multiprocessing when looping a simple range.

```
Process PoolWorker-37:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    sys.stdin.close()
AttributeError: StdIn instance has no attribute 'close'
```

The code

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
pool.map(get_info, range(20000,20010), 1)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

### Update

the first issue was by eclipse altering the environment, but now I get this error

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'cStringIO.StringO'>: attribute lookup cStringIO.StringO failed
```

Comment: Can you please give more detail about how are you running your script ? and can you add `import sys; print sys.stdin` in your script before this code, and tell us what is the output ?

Comment: print sys.stdin  = <open file '<stdin>', mode 'r' at 0xb7334020>. I executed it from eclipse with ipython, seems to work when executed normally. Why?

Comment: I think it's because eclipse console is changing your ``sys.stdin`` with the eclipse console one and i assume that the eclipse console stdin don't have a **close** method. FWIW this is one of the reason that i'm not using Eclipse anymore because it was changing the behaviour of my code.

Comment: If you're using Windows, did you make sure to put `if __name__ == '__main__':` before your main code ?

Comment: And also make sure you don't run your code from an interpreter..etc, run it as a script from CLI.

Comment: Run it on a ubuntu server (python 2.7.2), the script is using urllib2 so could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642107/python-pickling-error-when-using-sessions  and a connection issue .. anyway on my laptop (also with python 2.7.2) I get no error message.

Comment: For the record the last error relates to timeout with HTTP get url without exception handling, the error message from multiprocessing is just confusing..

Comment: For what it is worth I get the same error in PyCharm, but the issue is solved when I run the script in Enthought Canopy (and I'd guess in the Terminal)

Comment: "the first issue was by eclipse altering the environment" how have you solved this?

Answer (score 3):

This error is thrown if you are running in PyCharm console. I used the system console and all ran ok.

Answer (score 2):

In PyCharm 4.5 the solution for me was to remove "Show command line afterwards" checkbox in server Run/Debug configuration for python file (which is not even documented in PyCharm manual)

Comment: Could you be a little more clear where this lives?  Cant find it :|

Comment: If you are running the code from .py file with default PyCharm server - then:
Run-> Edit Configurations -> select your python run/debug configuration in left column -> "Show command line afterwards" checkbox in right column must be removed. Don't know what is the matter but it worked.